# Is there a way to select/apply a (or multiples) taxonomy value(s) to a particular asset using the governance Api?

Tags: registry, wso2, wso2-governance-registry

According to the documentation of the **wso2greg** , wso2greg provide different api types that enable us to interact with the registry , such as the registry-Api and the governance-Api, am already used the governance-Api to create some artifacts (wsdl ,xsd and serviceSoap with there dependancies) with java code and i already defined a taxonomy hierarchy via the WSO2 G-Reg Management , the next step **is to select a taxonomy value(s) for an asset** for example a soapService .

Am wondering if there's a way to do such a thing using the governance-Api.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, requested operation is yet to implement in G-Reg. Which means WSO2 haven't implemented API to do taxonomy operations. You can always log an issue in [GitHub](https://github.com/wso2/product-greg/issues) on this. If not you can checkout the code from GitHub build your own API for this. Please refer [this](https://docs.wso2.com/display/Governance540/Governance+API) link if you want to build that.

Comment: Thanks man , i really appreciate your answer , i guess i will try to build my own API